# Why is Mondrian MDX Query creating massive result set when properties are added?

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have relatively simple MDX query that is creating over 10,000 rows in a result set (most of them empty), but the SQL it generates creates relatively small number of rows in the result set.  Here is the MDX query:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY CrossJoin({([employmentDate.yearQuarterMonth].[2012]:[employmentDate.yearQuarterMonth].[2014])}, {[Measures].[headCount]}) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[residenceLocation].[iso_region].Members} ON ROWS
FROM workforce
```

This is an exert it returns:

```
|                                                 | 2012                 | 2013                 | 2014                 |
|                                                 | %{measure.headCount} | %{measure.headCount} | %{measure.headCount} |
+--------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Germany                  | #null                |                  138 |                  241 |                  238 |
| France                   | #null                |                   49 |                   40 |                   66 |
| United Kingdom           | #null                |                   46 |                   20 |                   33 |
| Japan                    | #null                |                   67 |                  135 |                  140 |
| Russian Federation       | #null                |                   84 |                  105 |                   78 |
| United States of America | California           |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
|                          |                      |                   38 |                   43 |                   36 |
```

You can see that it generates the states like California, but repeats that statistic over and over with an empty region names.

The SQL being generated is and it only returns 39 rows:

```
select
  "TIME"."YEAR" as "Year",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" as "Country",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_REGION" as "Region",
  sum("EMPLOYMENT"."HEADCOUNT") as "Headcount"
from
   "TIME" "TIME",
  "EMPLOYMENT" "EMPLOYMENT",
  "REGIONS" "REGIONS_1"
where
  "EMPLOYMENT"."EMPLOYMENT_DATE_ID" = "TIME"."ID"
and
  "TIME"."YEAR" in (2012, 2013, 2014)
and
  "EMPLOYMENT"."RESIDENCE_REGION_ID" = "REGIONS_1"."ID"
group by 
  "TIME"."YEAR",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_REGION";
```

Then this SQL for the properties being loaded and it returns over 20,000+:

```
select
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" as "Country Code",
  "REGIONS_1"."COUNTRY_NAME" as "Country",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" as "Country Code",
  "REGIONS_1"."LATITUDE" as "Latitude",
  "REGIONS_1"."LONGITUDE" as "Longitude",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_REGION" as "Region",
  "REGIONS_1"."REGION_NAME" as "Region Name",
  "REGIONS_1"."STATE_FIPS" as "State FIPS",
  "REGIONS_1"."LATITUDE" as "Latitude",
  "REGIONS_1"."LONGITUDE" as "Longitude"
from
  "REGIONS" "REGIONS_1"
group by
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE",
  "REGIONS_1"."COUNTRY_NAME",
  "REGIONS_1"."LATITUDE",
  "REGIONS_1"."LONGITUDE",
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_REGION",
  "REGIONS_1"."REGION_NAME",
  "REGIONS_1"."STATE_FIPS"
order by
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" ASC NULLS LAST,
  "REGIONS_1"."ISO_REGION" ASC NULLS LAST;
```

So I'm not sure why Mondrian is going crazy when it creates the CellSet.  The Region table is composed of these columns (but not all):

```
Country, 
Region (ISO Code), 
State_FIPS, 
Postal_Code, 
Latitude, 
Longitude, 
County, 
MSA, 
CBSA, etc.
```

It's a fairly low level Regional data.  The Dimension's hierarchy looks like this:

```
iso_country
  iso_region
    county
```

I should add that it also happens, but not to this degree, when using [residenceLocation].[country] where USA is blown out with several empty rows.  It includes maybe 10-20 extra rows, but not 10,000.  So I think it's the same problem in both cases.

**Update** I figured out where the extra rows are coming from.  When I add Latitude and Longitude as properties to Country, Region, and County then the rows begin to explode.  Take them away and it's ok.  So is there a way to add properties like these that could be different between rows without it affecting the returned CellSet?

Comment: something wrong in terms of relationships in the cubes. That repetition can occur when one selects a measure that is not related to the dimensions being used.

Comment: So if I removed my properties Latitude/Longitude (which is going to vary since may zipcodes are within a state for example) then the rows collapse, and it seems to be correct. Is that what you mean?  Is that an example of what you describe?

Comment: I was just commenting - if I knew the answer I would have added an answer. From experience I've seen this repetition of numbers when using a measure that is unrelated to some of the dimensions used. Although looking again maybe you need to add a conditional `IIF` into the mdx for the measure `headCount`.